# Problem using MQTT trigger from Azure Function via TLS

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-functions, mqtt

We want an Azure Function to be triggered by a new message being published to an MQTT topic. We use [CloudMQTT](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/) for hosting the broker, and [CaseOnline](https://github.com/keesschollaart81/CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt) for the trigger configuration. We want to use TLS and certificate validation.

It all works fine when locally debugging the Function, but when deploying to Azure, we get MqttCommunicationClosedGracefullyException and the connection is never really established.

We added the WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE application setting to the Azure Function, which we found was needed in order for it successfully load our PFX certificate.

However, can anyone help identify what may still be missing?

Comment: are you using azure functions on consumption plan or app service plan ? the documentation for the caseonline plugin says that it does not work on consumption plan.

Comment: We are using app service plan, so that was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared we must have been mixing things a bit, since when trying once adding the WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE application setting along with the PersistKeySet ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags?view=netframework-4.7.2)) flag for importing the PFX certificate, it worked perfectly.